# How to set a transparent photo in ios ? without coding

Tags: ios, image, transparent

Hi every one I want to set my image in xcode TRANSPARENT (1st photo). I just drag and drop the Image to View but after that I retry to redo my thing but can not(2nd photo). Anyone know how to do please help me.
ps: I dont want to write any code, just drag and drop

[image: this one is TRANSPARENT]
[image: this one is not TRANSPARENT]

Comment: honestly, your question description is poor. I don't get what you want to do, make image partly transparent or make text area background transparent or another thing.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you must set alpha parameter to the element you want to be transparent in the attribute inspector.

Comment: I checked my 2 photo my alpha parameter are still the same(alpha =1)

Comment: @tommy Mmm if you want to make your UIView partly transparent you must change alpha parameter, so try to change it.

Comment: Thank you vey much I can do it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just set a transparent background color for your text view. Check its *Attributes inspector*.-

[image]

Comment: I try but there is no "transparent background" for me to click on:(

Comment: Actually, xcode 'name' for transparent color is `Clear color`. It should appear on the bottom of the dropdown list when you click on `Background` field.

Comment: Thank you I can do it :D

Comment: Glad it helped :) By the way, if any answer was useful, please, consider upvoting/accepting so that other users can spot the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, do you mean you want the UITextView background to be transparent? If so, set the background color to clear color.

If you want an entire view to be transparent, set the alpha to a number between 0 and 1.